# Array.Contains() by value with arrays

Tags: c#, contains

How can I use `Contains()`, but with arrays being the compared objects? The difference here is that **I need to check the equality of the content of the array, not the memory addresses**. How can I do this?

```
var array = List<byte[]>();
var searchFor = new byte[23]; //has some value in it
array.Contains(searchFor); //Doesn't work properly
```

Comment: You need to use a custom equality comparer. `Contains()` has an overload for that.

Comment: I'd go with what @svick said, and if you the items should appear in the same order in both arrays, Jeroen's answer bellow will work as well ... (I'd still probably override the equality comparer though ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool containsArray = array.Any(a => a.SequenceEqual(searchFor));
```

If ordering does not matter for equality:

```
var orderedSearchFor = searchFor.OrderBy(x => x);
bool containsArray = 
      array.Any(a => a.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(orderedSearchFor));
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! Very nice. I love the simplification edits, haha

Answer (score 0):

To add to the selected answer, this is also possible

```
         bool found = (from c in array
                      where c.SequenceEqual(searchFor)
                      select c).Count() > 0;
```

Depending on if you want to use the query like style of LINQ.

Here is a working example:

```
        var array = new List<byte[]>();

        var searchFor = new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xA0 };

        array.Add(searchFor);

         bool found = (from c in array
                      where c.SequenceEqual(searchFor)
                      select c).Count() > 0;
```